# Ruby equivalent of Tie::FIle?

Tags: ruby, module

Is there a Ruby equivalent of Perl [Tie::File](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-File) module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

It's easy to read a file and return the lines as an `Array`, just as in Perl:

```
array = File.readlines("testfile")
```

But I don't think there's a library that makes sure all operations on `array` are reflected in the original file (or is more efficient for large files than the naive approach above).

Comment: Correct answer, however it should be noted that Tie::File does a memory map of a file on disk and thus provides scalable access to huge files.  This is not the same as reading the whole file into memory, which would be limited by available memory.

Comment: @Svante, agreed; added a short remark to stress performance considerations.